# How to convert data to JSON after making API call in react

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm new to React and I get an error in my console (see below) when I try to convert data to JSON. This is probably not the correct way of doing it. Anyone knows how to fix this? I want to display the fetched data in my console.

> App.js:27 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

App.js

```
const API_ID = "xxxxx";
const API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx";

class App extends Component{
  //function to get recipe
  getRecipe = async (e) => {
    const recipeName = e.target.elements.recipeName.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    const api_call = await fetch(`curl "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free"
    `);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: This error usually happens for me if invalid data is returned from the API (curl in your case). Can you double check to make sure the data you are receiving is correct? Perhaps console.log(api_call) to confirm?

Comment: can you try to remove the curl in fetch, and try hitting it and where are you calling the function getRecipe,

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS thank you so much! I totally forgot o remove curl in fetch :) Thank you!

Comment: @PetraJakubcova I have added the answer kindly vote and accept if it worked and helped you to solve the issue , Happy coding :)

Comment: @PetraJakubcova did it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) needs only the URL you're making the http request to as first param.

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free');
const jsonResponse = await response.json();
```

You are correct to parse the response to json afterwards, but when the url is incorrect, fetch will return empty response. Trying to parse the empty response will result in the error you've described.

Just to make things clear, [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) is a cli tool (not js browser api, like fetch) that performs http requests. It does the same job as fetch, but in different contexts. So you do not need to call it, or specify it as part of the url you provide to fetch.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the question in the code snippet there was a adding of curl as shown below

Instead of this

```
const api_call = await fetch(`curl "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free"`);
```

Use

```
const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free"`);
```

Kindly remove it and i hope it should work.